# Finding the numbers that satisfies the boxes

Tags: systems-of-equations, puzzle

How do you solve this question
I represented the unknown numbers that add to give 8 and subtract to give 6 by x and y. I solved it and had 7 and 1. But they don't match with the 13 and 8 below the boxes

I'm stuck

$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
\Box&+&\Box&=&8\\
+&&+\\
\Box&-&\Box&=&6\\
=&&=\\
13&&8\end{array}$$

Comment: This should not be tagged "algebraic geometry"

Comment: Just didn't know the tags to use

Comment: Let the two numbers in the top row be $a$ and $b$, and let the two numbers in the bottom row be $c$ and $d$. Then you have $$a + b = 8$$ $$a + c = 13$$ $$b + d = 8$$ $$c - d = 6$$ You can now solve the system easily by repeated [substitution or elimination](https://www.dummies.com/education/math/calculus/how-to-solve-linear-systems-using-substitution-or-elimination/). Good luck!

Comment: In the four boxes you can use different numbers, so in the second line you don't have to use the same x and y.

Comment: You can also row reduce the corresponding augmented coefficient matrix:

$$\left[
  \begin{matrix}
    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
  \end{matrix}
  \left|
    \,
    \begin{matrix}
      8  \\
      13  \\
      8  \\
      6  \\
    \end{matrix}
  \right.
\right]$$

Comment: From the setting I would expect the numbers to enter in the boxes to be whole.  They cannot be, as the answers show.  One can view this as a defect in the problem or as a requirement to think outside the box(es).  I would need more context to decide between the alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

As a linear system, assuming $x_1$ is the lower-left box and proceeding counterclockwise, we have
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&-1&0&0\\
0&1&1&0\\
0&0&1&1\\
1&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\mathbf x=\begin{bmatrix}6\\8\\8\\13\end{bmatrix}$$
From this we get the unique solution
$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
3.5&+&4.5&=&8\\
+&&+\\
9.5&-&3.5&=&6\\
=&&=\\
13&&8\end{array}$$

Answer (score 1):

You can set up four equations from this. I will assign variables for each corner. Top left is a. Top right is b. Bottom left is c, and bottom right is d.

So these are the equations that are able to be set up.

$a+b=8$, $a+c=13$, $b+d=8$, $c-d=6$

So, let us combine the first two equations.

$ \ \ \ \ \ a+b=8$

$-(a+c=13)$

==================

$b-c=-5$

Now, let us combine the last two equations.

$ \ \ \ \ \ b+d=8$

$+(c-d=6)$

==================

$b+c=14$

---

We now use the two derived equations to solve for either b or c.

$ \ \ \ \ \ b-c=-5$

$+(b+c=14)$

==================

$2b = 9$

$\therefore b = 4.5$

With this being said, plug $b$ back into the equation and get $c$. $b+c=14$ So, $4.5+c=14$.

$\therefore c=9.5$

Plug $b$ and $c$ back into the rest of the equations to get the variables.

$a+b=8 \therefore a=3.5$

$c-d=6 \therefore d=3.5$

Therefore, the answers to the question is: Top Left: 3.5, Top Right: 4.5, Bottom Left: 9.5, Bottom Right: 3.5